# Get render value of datatable column instead of data value

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am getting my datatable data from ajax.
My table have `name` `surname` and `status` columns
I am getting `status` from database as `0` or `1` for `active` and `inactive`
after getting the data I render it with like this

```
"columns": [
        {
          "data": "name"
        },
        {
          "data": "surname"
        },
         {
          "data": "status",
          "render": function(data, type, row) {
            if (data == '1') {
              return '<div class="badge badge-green">active</div>';
            } else {
              return '<div class="badge badge-red">inactive</div>';
            }
          }
        }
]
```

And after rendering the data I am getting dynamically all the statuses in the table and appened it to select element for extra filteration.

I used initComplete function to get values and append it as follows:

```
initComplete: function() {
      
        // select status column
        dataTable.column(2).data().unique().sort().each(function(data, j) {
          $('#filterByStatus').append('<option value="' + data + '">' + data + '</option>');
        });
         
      }
```

The thing is since my actual data are `0`s and `1`s the function I am using is printing `0` and `1` in the select option **not** the rendered data which are `active` and `inactive`.

How to to get the rendered values of cell? like this

```
<option value="active">active</option>
<option value="inactive">inactive</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues and i fixed it by calling the same function again. hope this helps

```
"initComplete": function (){
        this.api().columns([2,7,9]).every( function ()
        {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>').appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty()).on( 'change', function () {var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(this).val());
            column.search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false ).draw();
            });       
   $col=column[0];
   if($col==9){
       column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ){
           $val=StatusFormatter(d);
           select.append( '<option value="'+$val+'">'+$val+'</option>' )
       });
   }
   else{
       column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ){
           select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
       });
   } 
        });
    }
```